# Make menu items align the same when adding border on hover

Tags: html, css

This is my code and I want the alignment to be the same

When I insert a `border-left` my text goes a bit to the right side but I want all the text to align in the same way.

When I hover it also there the same case.

If I remove the `border-left` then the text alignment is fine, but how do i get the same alignment when there is border?

```
<div class="set-leftcol">
  <div class="leftcol-box">
    <div class="leftcol active">
       <div class="sett-i"><i class="fa fa-cog "></i></div>
       <div class="sett-title">General</div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftcol">
       <div class="sett-i"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
       <div class="sett-title">Security</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="leftcol-box">
    <div class="leftcol">
       <div class="sett-i"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
       <div class="sett-title">Privacy</div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftcol">
       <div class="sett-i"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></div>
       <div class="sett-title">Timeline</div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftcol">
       <div class="sett-i"></div>
       <div class="sett-title">Blocking</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="leftcol-box">
    <div class="leftcol">
       <div class="sett-i"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></div>
       <div class="sett-title">Notification</div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftcol">
       <div class="sett-i"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></div>
       <div class="sett-title">Mobile</div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftcol">
       <div class="sett-i"><i class="fa fa-rss-square"></i></div>
       <div class="sett-title">Followers</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqGRqG

Comment: Show your css ? Provide a jsfiddle, can be great so you can try `box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: This is my Codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqGRqG

Comment: Now to which select do I need to insert the box-sizing?

Comment: You can add margin-left: -4px; and width: 257px; to .leftcol.active and .leftcol:hover -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJerPY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `.leftcol` to this :

```
.leftcol {
   float: left;
   clear: both;
   width: 250px;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #EBF9FF;
   border-left: 4px solid  transparent;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNpdZE)

Answer (score 1):

The wrong alignment is caused by the `:hover` state adding a 4px border, so the element is a bit wider when hovered.

One way to prevent that is to add a transparent border to the `.leftcol` elements, so that when they are hovered only the border color changes but not the width:

```
.leftcol {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Another option would be to use 4px padding on it, and remove that on hover. This is essentially the same trick as above, but uses a padding placeholder for non-hovered elements:

```
.leftcol {
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.leftcol:hover {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have intentionally complicated the markup to this extent because you need to do something further with the empty `<div>`s or have done so accidentally.

In case you didn't have a better way to figure it out, I suggest you take a look at my pen below:
[Codepen link to simplify the above markup](http://codepen.io/ikartik90/pen/waKzJK)

I have stripped down your markup to the minimal level and yet achieved the same result you were expecting. Hope it helps you out. Cheers!